# bash if statement with strings always evaluates to true

Tags: bash, if-statement

I am getting started with bash and am having trouble with if statements. 
Why does the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
read C
if  (( $C == 'Y' )) ; then
    echo "YES"
elif (( $C == 'N' )) ; then
    echo "NO"
fi
```

Seem to print `YES` no matter what value `$C` takes on.

Comment: `((...))` is for math expressions. You want `if [[ $C = 'Y' ]]`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings inside the arithmetic statement `((...))` are recursively expanded until you either get an integer value (including 0 for an undefined parameter) or a string that causes a syntax error. Some examples:

```
# x expands to y, and y expands to 3
$ x=y y=3
$ (( x == 3 )) && echo true
true

$ x="foo bar"
$ (( x == 3 ))
bash: ((: foo bar: syntax error in expression (error token is "bar")

# An undefined parameter expands to 0
$ unset x
$ (( x == 0 )) && echo true
true
```

In your case, `$C` expands to some undefined parameter name, and both it and `Y` expand to 0, and 0 == 0.

For string comparison, use `[[ ... ]]` instead.

```
if [[ $C == Y ]]; then
```

Answer (score 1):

Yep, as @larsks mentioned, you need the square brackets. Try this full version:

```
#!/bin/bash

read C
if [[ ${C} == 'Y' ]]; then
    echo "YES"
elif [[ ${C} == 'N' ]]; then
    echo "NO"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the right format.

```
#!/bin/bash
read C
if  [[ $C == 'Y' ]]
then
    echo "YES"
elif [[ $C == 'N' ]]
then
    echo "NO"
fi
```

Comment: You'd better use `[[ ]]` instead of `[ ]`. Because if `C` is empty, `[ $C == 'Y' ]` will throw error just like: `-bash: [: ==: unary operator expected`, while `[[ ${C} == 'Y' ]]` won't.

Comment: @Weike Thanks for this knowledge! I never know that before. It has been updated.